# Google Cloud function to update Users Firestore DB when sub-collection is updated

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Disclosure: I'm new to Cloud Functions. I am trying to create and deploy a function with Firebase ClI but I'm getting an error in the deployment phase.

**Context**:
I have a Users Firestore Database and each user in it has a Checkout subcollection.
I need to update a field called **checkoutTotal** in each user document based on the items they have in the checkout subcollection by multiplying the price * quantity for each item and add them all up.

**Goal**:
My goal is to create a Function called update_total_value() that goes through every item in the Checkout subcollection, get the total amount (price * quantity) and adds all up in the checkoutTotal field in the users database. It should be triggered every time the checkout subcollection is created, updated, deleted.

This is what I have so far in my main.py file inside functions folder:

```
import firebase_admin
import firebase_functions

def initialize_app():
    """Initializes the Firebase Admin SDK."""
    firebase_admin.initialize_app()

def update_total_value(event, context):
    """Updates the totalValue field in the users database with the multiplication of price and quantity of each item in the checkout and then adds all the values inside the checkout, in order to give the total value of all checkout items of each user."""

    # Get the user ID from the event context.
    user_id = context.params["user_id"]

    # Get a reference to the checkout subcollection of the user document.
    checkout_ref = firestore.client().collection("users").document(user_id).collection("checkout")

    # Get a list of all documents in the checkout subcollection.
    checkout_docs = checkout_ref.get()

    # Calculate the total value of the user's checkout by summing the price * quantity fields of all documents in the checkout subcollection.
    total_value = 0
    for doc in checkout_docs:
        total_value += doc.data()["price"] * doc.data()["quantity"]

    # Update the user document in the users collection with the total value of the checkout.
    user_ref = firebase_admin.firestore.client().collection("users").document(user_id)
    user_ref.update({"checkoutTotal": total_value})

    # Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
    initialize_app()

    # Deploy the Cloud Function.
    firebase_admin.functions.on_firestore_write(update_total_value)
```

I'm always getting an error:

```
[2023-11-02 14:40:09,933] ERROR in app: Exception on /__/functions.yaml [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\firebase_functions\private\serving.py", line 122, in get_functions_yaml
    functions = get_functions()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\venv\Lib\site-packages\firebase_functions\private\serving.py", line 40, in get_functions
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\guilh\myproject\functions\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    firebase_admin.functions.on_firestore_write(update_total_value)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'firebase_admin' has no attribute 'functions'

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2023 14:40:09] "GET /__/functions.yaml HTTP/1.1" 500 -

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2023 14:40:09] "GET /__/quitquitquit HTTP/1.1" 200 -


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this outside of your function. The initializing of the app and deploying of the cloud function is not done within the cloud function itself.

```
    # Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
    initialize_app()

    # Deploy the Cloud Function.
    firebase_admin.functions.on_firestore_write(update_total_value)
```